# MVC View. List of strings. Conditionally use DateTime EditorTemplate on List Item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The View  is an 'Application Form'

The model is an 'Application' object.

The Application object contains a Person object  and an array of Question objects.

Each question has:

- A text field containing the question
- A numeric field containing  the question type (1= number , 2 = string,3=Date etc)
- A text field for the response. The response field is preloaded with an example  (In the case of Dates it is DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())

The View has a form containing the Person details and  a table which contains the question list. The Applicant fills in the Response fields and submits. This works.

I now want to present the Date type questions with a DatetimePicker.

Using a Razor 'if' statement on the questionType field  I can separate out the datetime questions from the others in the list display.

For the Datetype questions  I want to call a DateTime Picker EditorTemplate.

```
 <td>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @{
                            if (Model.Responses[i].QuestionTypeId == 3)
                            {
                                @Html.EditorFor(p => p.Responses[i].Response,"DateTime")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Responses[i].Response)

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Responses[i].Response)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Responses[i].Response)
                            }
                        }

                        @*@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Responses[i].Response)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Responses[i].Response)*@
                    </div>
                </td>
```

To get the  DateTime.cshtml EditorTemplate to run, I had to make the model type a string.

Although it gets called, it doesn't execute the datepicker javascript.

I assume this is because the underlying Model field type is a string.

I tried making a date out of the string in the Template and passing the date into the Template TextBox call but this had no effect.

Is there a way past this?

EditorTemplate code currently is:

```
 @model System.String
 @{ DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(Model);}  
 @Html.TextBox("", myDate,new { @class = "datePicker" , 
    })
 @section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/cssjqryUi")
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".datePicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/images/calendar-icon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date"
    });
});
</script>
 }
```

Comment: Why would you need to make it a `string`? And scripts should never be in templates (or partials) - only in the main view of layout. Just use `TextBoxFor()` and give it a class name, and in the main view use `$(".datePicker").datepicker({ .....`

Comment: The data originates from a system where the question responses are strings. It is a generic 'application' system where the user decides what form an Application should take. Think of someone doing a pencilled form for a new application, photo copying it and handing it out. The questions will be determined by the 'application' need. Hence the Question.Response field is a string. It could be a 'number' or a 'date' or a 'true / false' or an amount $0.00. The reference has to be back to model so that the submitted object is intact. i.e. Array of questions displayed. Array of questions submitted.

Comment: Actually your question made me reconsider the design. There is no reason the dates can't be moved out of the list as they will be a feature of every application. This will solve the problem. They can appear as Date types in say a 'Range Object'. If you frame your comment as an answer I will mark it as accepted. Thanks